# SMTP Server and HTTP Server on a single VPS

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp, http, vps

I have a VPS (CentOS 7) with an Apache HTTP server already running on it, with its own domain. But, I also want to send emails from that domain, so that I have a website called example.com and I can send emails as johnsmith@example.com.

I know that one can use a SMTP server on their VPS, and I have heard of it being possible to have 2 servers at once on a single VPS.

So I have set up postfix on my VPS and I can send emails from localhost to localhost, but I don't know how to set up the DNS records. I cannot point to mail.example.com because that google domains tells me that the record is already in use. Does anyone know how to go about this?

Comment: You can run any number of services on one VPS, if it has the resources. Running an email server can have overhead with spam filtering, spam lists, etc. Best just use a hosted email service - AuthSMTP, Amazon SES, Google Main, Office 365, etc.

Comment: @davidgo This question is about _sending_ email from the server, not a complete mail setup that would also be receiving mail; no `MX` records involved. Securing such an installation is a lot easier, but does require some expertise, too.

Comment: @Esa Jokinen Good catch.

Comment: What SMTP server are you running.   You don't actually need to make any changes to your DNS unless you are using SPF.  Assuming the mail server is just for sending emails from sites already on that box, have them connect to "localhost".  Rather then setting up a complete mail server, it often makes sense to set your mail server up as a mail relay, which instructs it to forward all email on through a full mail server.

Comment: I have postfix running. What mail server would I forward through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you only want to send e-mail that's originating from that server, for example automatic maintenance emails, webforms as part of a web application or something like that, you don't need to configure any new MX records (these are only used for routing incoming email).

1. You'll need to configure PostFix as a relay that only accepts email from the local host. [Here's a good guide on how that's done.](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-setup-postfix-as-send-only-mail-server-on-an-ubuntu-18-04-dedicated-server-or-vps/) It's very important that you configure this correctly, otherwise your Postfix server could be used to send spam all over the world without your consent.
2. If your domain uses SPF (Sender Policy Framework) you'll need to add the IP address of your VPS to the SPF record. SPF tells receivers that what mail servers are authorised to send email for a particular domain, so if you don't add your VPS to that list, most receivers will flag incoming email from that server as spam.